# Can viewing or deploying a report from Visual Studio break its exports?

Tags: excel, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am having some problems with SSRS reports a former employee created.
The first problem comes when exporting the report results to Excel. They throw an error "We found a problem with some content. Do you want to try to recover?" and then the recovery doesn't quite work.
Exporting to other file types, like PDF or Word, works.
Secondly, trying to view the reports from inside Visual Studio gives the error "An error occurred during local report processing."
No changes have been made to the reports and their respective VS projects have been recovered from data backups.
Can I somehow redeploy without using Visual Studio? How do I troubleshoot what is causing the error if nothing has changed? Does using a newer version of Visual Studio somehow break formatting in reports made in earlier versions?

Edit: Even when the query that builds report returns NO DATA, the errors still happen.

Comment: You check the Errors tab in Visual Studio. They should give a better error message. If you have a `SELECT *` in the dataset and the fields changed, you may get errors like this. You could copy the RDL from Visual Studio's file location and `Upload` in Report Server but if it doesn't work in VS, it probably won't work in RS.

Comment: Thank you, Hannover Fist. Ultimately, I went through and deleted each element of the report one by one until it rendered without errors. There was a table used to display the data and that was somehow the problem. Deleted the table, recreated it, and problem solved.